# Does aggregation order affect performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance, explain

I read on a blog that changing the order of aggregation (using `group by 1,2` instead of `group by 2,1` can affect the performance of the query.

But the costs of both the query plans are identical. Yet, they claim a performance improvement in execution times.

Is this actually possible?

https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/speeding-up-group-by-in-postgresql/

Comment: Aggregation is GROUP BY, not ORDER BY. When you alter expressions order in the ordering expression than this shouldn't effect the performance until an index may be used for one of the variants. Of course the same can be told about grouping, but the probability that some index may be used for aggregation is higher.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad typo. I meant aggregation, `group by`. Is `group by 1,2` different from `group by 2,1`, performance wise, all else remaining constant?

Comment: When there is no indices (like in the article) then the factor mentioned in the article can really take place.

Comment: That article was written for PostgreSQL 11. 15 was just released. You may see differences in behavior now. Always good to check the versions because PostgreSQL moves fast and changes over time.

Comment: @Akina Can the execution times be different even with the identical query plan?

Comment: @GrantFritchey even in the article, the execution plans are the same in either case...

Comment: The article includes the instructions for repeating the test.  If you really want to know if it works, try it and see.  If you don't believe Schönig, why would you believe us when we tell you the same thing?

Comment: *Can the execution times be different even with the identical query plan?* In theory - yes. But in practice the difference may be a measurement accuracy and concurrent processes effect. [test fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qCLQjkKX) - reRun it for the same or another version and compare 'Execution Time:' values. Also you may vary the experiment parameters values (but remember that fiddle server resources may be limited which may result in error).